# Problem with writting correctly a query posts args in Wordpress

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, order

In my posts custom fields, I have a meta_key named ending. The value of it is a date in the form of 30-11-2011 (dd-mm-yyyy).

I tried this below but with no luck.

`query_posts("paged=$paged&meta_key=ending&order_by=meta_value&order=DESC")`

I also tried to do it like below, again with no correct output using my date format

```
$querystr = "
    SELECT wposts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
    AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'ending' 
    ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value ASC
    ";


 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

?>
 <?php if ($pageposts): ?>
  <?php global $post; ?>
  <?php foreach ($pageposts as $post): ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>


      <?php the_title(); ?>
<br>
  <?php endforeach; ?>

  <?php else : ?>

 <?php endif; ?>
```

There are two points I concern.

1. Is my query_posts correct?
2. Is the format of the date I type into the custom field, ideal for this?

Thank you for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad1. meta_values are strings, so they are ordered like strings, not dates. 
In SQL you should use some casting as a DATE before ordering

ad2. better date format would be yyyy-mm-dd, because sorting this meta field like strings gives the same results as date-type column..

compare order of dates in yyyy-mm-dd

```
2010-03-06
2012-06-05
```

and the same dates in dd-mm-yyyy

```
05-06-2012
06-03-2010
```

both are sorted (ASC), but the first example is in correct order.